# Existing Salesforce integration to existing ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

I have a client who is an existing user of Salesforce and an existing user of ExactTarget but the systems have never been integrated.  What do we need to look out for beyond installing the v5 integration?  Do we need to perform a data sync prior to connecting the two systems?  Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to your ET Relationship Manager.  There are some pre-requisites that need to be completed before installing.  

Also, V5 Requires enabling Subscriber Key on your ExactTarget account if it is not already...see below for some further info.  

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/salesforce_v5_install_guide/prerequisites_and_critical_concepts/

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/subscriber_key/